# System class & println() method

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
class Temp
{
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("abc.txt");
        PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(fout);
        System.out.println("Hello");
        System.setOut(ps);
        System.out.println("Hay");
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what happens in above code. I am unable to understand why it shows only  **Hello** in the output. If you cover some concepts of **System** class while explaining then it will be more beneficial for me.

Comment: read about it here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`System.out` is a static variable in the `System` class which refers to a `PrintStream` object. By default it refers to an object whose output goes to the standard output.

Therefore the output of `System.out.println("Hello")` is displayed in the standard output. When you call `System.setOut(ps)`, you change `System.out` to refer to a `PrintStream` whose output goes to the file "abc.txt". Therefore, `System.out.println("Hay");` writes "Hay" to that file.